# TortoiseSVN cannot commit, says "forbidden by server"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, renaming

Recently a bunch of renaming changes were made into a folder that I checked out a while ago. Once I updated all of the renaming changes, I am having a problem of not being able to commit anything. It says the following:

[image]

I am able to read, write, and update new files. I just cannot commit.

I think I tried almost everything - doing a cleanup, deleting and rechecking out the folder...

I have googled this problem and someone mentioned a case-sensitive issue when checking out the repository, but I am sure I have the svn repository url correct. Note that everything was working (commits and all) before the whole renaming changes.

Does anyone have any clues ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the server hosting your SVN repository, check to see if you have permission to the write to the folder you checked out. If not, you should contact the administrator of the repository and have them verify your access permissions.

Comment: Are you using `file://` as a Subversion URL by any chance?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. It occurred when I was adding a new User Group to one of the Repositories. I accidently set my highest UserGroup to Read-Only, without realising I was in it. I ended up being unable to suddenly commit any file or creating any new folder, because of the way SVN access works.

First make sure your URL exactly matches the Repository, that seems to be the most common problem, then [read this](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) and check your access as Bernard suggested.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue. I was in two user groups. one that had read only and the second one that had read/write. The second groups was permissioned at the root of the repo and the more restricted group was permissioned below that. This error message sums it up correctly. The server decided you don't have write permissions.

Comment: I also had exactly the same problem. The user group I am belonging yo has been changed to Read-Only. Despite I had an explicit Read-Write privilege, I couldn't commit anymore. Commits were rejected with the error message mentioned in the question above. After removing and adding again of my user with Read / Write permissions on the security page, everything worked as expected, i.e. I could commit my changes.

Comment: Fix this problem by change the server folder premission. Set Everyone can full control the folder. But do it by your own risk. My server using the windows server 2019 os.

Answer (score 2):

Please Make sure that you have entered the correct username as it is **case-sensitive** it usually happens when username doesn't match the case on wordpress.org . I've already lost hours to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem when using CollabNet Subversion Edge. The fix was to make sure that the groups defined in our Repository Access Rules had references to other groups by using the @ prefix. Better explained with an example:

Repository access rule:

```
[MyRepository:/branches/dev]
* = r
@admin = rw
@dev = rw
```

`[groups]` before:

```
admin=user1,user2
dev=user3,user4
```

`[groups]` after:

```
admin=user1,user2
dev=@admin,user3,user4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I am using Tortoise SVN. In my case, I have two groups say for example 'a-grp' and 'b-grp'. The user id (say for example 1234) for which the commit access is denied is available in both the groups.
 The 'rw' permission is given to the group 'a-grp' for the root folder level. 
 The 'r' permission is given to the group 'b-grp' for the subfolder level in the root folder.
That is the issue.


My fault Repository access rule:

```
reqdocs=1234, 5696, 7458
testdocs=1234, 5525, 9969, 4444
<br>
[MyRepository:/branches/rootfolder]
@reqdocs= rw
<br>
[MyRepository:/branches/rootfolder/subfolder]
@testdocs= r
```

Hence I removed the user id (1234) from the 'testdocs' group. Now its working.
Hope it helps. Thank you.